# Etherscan API: get the list of the Non-Fungible Token Transfers with API

Tags: etherscan, erc721

this https://etherscan.io/tokentxns-nft can be a good example of what I would get from Etherscan API, a list with all the transfers related to a specific NFT collection. Moreover, I would include the ETH exchanged for every transfer, a list of target fields below:

- Txn Hash
- Age
- From
- To
- TokenID
- Token
- ETH value exchanged in this transfer

is there any API in Etherscan that can let me collect that information?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this API endpoint for Ropsten Network. It will provide you all the details with tokenID and other requirements you listed above.

https://api-ropsten.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=tokennfttx&address=<your_Contract_Address>&startblock=0&endblock=latest&sort=asc&apikey=<your_API_key>

I am using Ropsten API because my contract is deployed on Ropsten Testnet. You can adjust block with your starting block.

Comment: thank you for the response, the missing pieces of information are related to value exchanged for an NFT. For example, in the API you suggested, I can see that X send to Y and NFT of contract W and id Z, but nowhere there is the information that Y send to X a value of some ETH as the exchange of the asset, as it can happen in any marketplace.